# Implement swipe for news change like inshorts app in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

strong text[image]want to implement swipe news in ionic like in-shorts app [image].i want to show vertical view inside ionic content anyone help me out for this.https://github.com/vikrantsharma123/ios-inshorts-view

Comment: https://github.com/loringdodge/ionic-ion-tinder-cards-2 check this once

Comment: i want page wise  data http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/#.WKq1RvJGRU1 check this check vertical Demo